# How to Open .PPS File in Website Without Downloading or Without Converting Format

Tags: jquery

How to Open presentation File in Website Without Downloading or Without Converting   to other Format...

```
1)i can able to disbly swf file in website without downloading..If i display .pps file ,it's downloading automatically in Chrome browser..

Is there any Possibilities to display pps file in website..
```

Below my code

Comment: Please post what code you've tried.

Comment: <embed src="psdm.swf" width="800" height="200" style="border:1px solid">

Comment: Just Manually converted to swf format and displaying in website...